# Block other common xmpp clients from logging in XMPP

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I want to prevent the common xmpp client's (such as Pidgin,PSI+,...) from logging in the our xmpp server(ejabberd). How can i acheive this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to implement an proprietary authentication mechanism that these clients didn't support. That would stop most, if not all, clients. Of course, someone could always fork an existing client and add support for this auth mechanism. Depends on how popular your service is...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that can be really be done. Of course you could cheat and just disconnect clients who *declare* themselves thru DiscoInfo, but that's easy not to declare who you are.

Also, this is just plain dumb. XMPP is an open protocol for *that specific purpose*: so that clients and server who dont know each other can still communicate using a common protocol. It's like if you asked "how can I shutdown my website for the folks who use Firefox".

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to prevent *any* person from using your xmpp server via an unauthorized client: Psi, Adium, etc; or are you trying to prevent *unauthorized people,* perhaps from outside of your organization from using your xmpp server? The former goes against the design goals of xmpp. If you are trying to accomplish the latter: **turn off registration**. You will need to come up with a procedure that creates initial username/password tokens which allow *authorized* people into the server. And you probably want **enable user password changes**. These procedures may be partially or fully manual depending on what's appropriate for your organization. If your organization is large enough to centrally manage users via LDAP/Active Directory you can use LDAP authentication with most xmpp servers and with the appropriate filtering you can even configure things so a subset of your users will be allowed access to xmpp while others outside of that subset will be denied access.